# How to log some, but not all, lftp transfers

Tags: linux, logging, lftp

I have an lftp script file that I use for mirroring some directories over sftp, so I run the command using something like `lftp -f mirror_dirs.lftp`. I would now like to log the transfers to a *specific log file* so that later, perhaps in a forensic context, I can determine what files were transferred and when. I don't want to put options in a file like `~/.lftp/rc` since I don't want to pollute my log file with information from other, ad-hoc, lftp commands I might issue. I have read the [lftp manual](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) and remain quite confused.

It seems like what I want to do is log transfers. The manual mentions the following:

> ```
>    log:enabled (boolean)
>           when  true,  the  log messages are output. The closure for this
>           and other 'log:' variables is either `debug' for debug messages
>           or 'xfer' for transfer logging.
>
>    log:file (string)
>           the target output file for logging. When empty, stderr is used.
> ```

This "closure" business is particularly confusing to me, as is its syntax. As far as I can tell the "closure" is a way to provide a more specific context for a command. Here was my initial attempt:

```
set log/xfer:enabled true
set log/xfer:file "/Logs/lftp_transfer.log"
set log/xfer:show-time true
set mirror:parallel-directories true

open "sftp://user99:passwordXYZ@example.com"
mirror --verbose -c / tests/
```

which resulted in the error message `/Logs/lftp_transfer.log: invalid boolean value`, so obviously I have not understood the syntax.

How can I correctly specify transfer logging in an lftp script file.

Comment: Please try `set xfer:log 1
set xfer:log-file "/Logs/lftp_transfer.log"`

Comment: @BANJOSA: Ok, that seemed to work perfectly, thanks. I wonder what all that business about "closures" was in the manual. Also, I didn't see those settings mentioned anywhere in the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your configuration to:

```
set xfer:log 1 
set xfer:log-file "/Logs/lftp_transfer.log"
```